# Is the union of two tangent open disks a connected set?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, path-connected

I have a problem defining whether the set $A$ that we get as the union of two tangent open disks  is an open set. On the one hand we can select two sets: $B$ as the first disk and $C$ as the second one. Then $B\cup C=A$ ,$B\cap C=\emptyset$ ,$B\neq \emptyset$ , $C\neq \emptyset$ and $B$ does not contain any limt points of $C$ neither does $C$ contain any limit points of $B$.Taking this into consideration we can tell that $A$ is not a connected set. However using another definition of connected sets we can find a sequence of n points: $z_k$ such that $|z_{k-1}-z_k|<r , \quad \forall r>0$ through which any points $\alpha,\beta\in A$ are connected even for the case that the two points belong each to a different disk and so $A$ is considered a connected set. What is my mistake that makes this contradiction arise. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why are the points $\alpha, \beta$ connected if they belong to other sets?

Comment: @psl2Z I was saiyng that $\alpha,\beta$ belong to the same set $A$ but the one of the two : lets say $\alpha \in B $ and $\beta \in C$ .Then we can find a sequence of points that will connect the two points since  two points of the different disks that approach the single point of contact of the two disks can get infinitely close to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you shown, $A$ is not connected but it is [well-chained](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2314959). There is no contradiction: every connected metric space is well-chained but a well-chained metric space is not necessarily connected (think of $\mathbb Q$, or $\mathbb R^*$). What is true (but out of subject here) is that every *compact* well-chained metric space is connected.